# RSS feed excerpt doesn't display the excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I am trying to display the excerpt in a custom feed page, using `the_excerpt_rss()` function, I already set the **summary** show mode in **Settings->Reading** but it returns me the first paragraph of content, is there any another function to call just the excerpt, I already try with `the_excerpt()` and `get_the_excerpt()`?

Here is my code:

`<description><![CDATA[<?php html_entity_decode(preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "",the_excerpt_rss())); ?>]]></description>`

Comment: Is there exists excerpt content on every single post? because of the first paragraph consider as excerpt content when it's missing in the post or blank in the post.

Comment: No it's not in every single post, but there are posts that has excerpt, and it doesn't show on these posts?

Answer (score 0):

I had found a solution. So I customized the function `add_feed_content($content)`:

```
function add_feed_content($content) {
    global $post;
    $excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;

    if(is_feed()) {
        if (strlen($excerpt) > 0){
            $content = '';
            $content .= $excerpt;
            return $content;
        } else {
            return $content;
        }
    }
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'add_feed_content');
```